# Slow hashcat after resume

Tags: password

```
Input.Mode: Dict (wordlist.txt)
Index.....: 4/1265 (segment), 2994585 (words), 33550344 (bytes)
Recovered.: 0/1 hashes, 0/1 salts
Speed/sec.: 601 plains, 601 words
Progress..: 1854564/2994585 (61.93%)
Running...: 00:00:51:27
Estimated.: 00:00:31:36


[s]tatus [p]ause [r]esume [b]ypass [q]uit =>
```

After I paused hashcat that did ~1600/second pw, I did a half hour suspend, then turned on the laptop, resumed, and it did only about ~200 password per second, and it increases very slowly. After 15 minutes it is about ~600 pw/sec. Using the latest hashcat, rhel 7.

**Question:** Did I found a bug relating the "Speed/sec" line? It uses all my CPU as usual, maybe it still does 1600 pw/sec in reality, but it shows it incorretly because I suspended my notebook for half an hour?

Comment: That's a good guess. Simple to answer—calculate the speed yourself using it's "progress" line and a stopwatch.

Comment: after 30 minutes, it's again 1600 pw/sec!